# How do I supply /highentropyva to compiler in .NET core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I am working on a .NET core project and I want to pass /highentropyva option to compiler. I tried to edit the xproj file by adding the following property, but no success, although it works with csproj file.

```
<HighEntropyVA>true</HighEntropyVA>
```

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: I don't see it listed in the schema.  Looking forward to this blasted json format getting retired at the next point release.  Soon, you can wait.

Comment: Does that even make sense, since .Net Core executables are actually .Net libraries?